# Dropdownlist no envía el valor(0) al controlador ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlist

Tengo un formulario en MVC ASP.NET, el cual funciona como modificador de roles de los usuarios que crean una cuenta en el sitio. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar el dropdownlist se muestran las opciones: 1-Usuario,2-Empleado,3-Administrador; en ese caso deseo pasar a este usuario del rol 1-Usuario al rol 2-Empleado y hasta ahí el rol que elegí para el usuario se muestra en el dropdownlist pero al presionar el botón guardar comienza el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ver este error pensé que había cometido un error con las referencias de las llaves foráneas al momento de crear la base de datos pero al hacer la prueba del procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server vi que funcionaba de manera correcta. El procedimiento almacenado pide el ID del usuario y el valor numérico del rol.
Comencé a depurar el código y vi que al seleccionar la opción y presionar el botón guardar, el valor (value) de la opción no se envía al controlador, solamente se envia el ID del usuario.
Este es el código del controlador:

```
 //Método que carga el una variable del diccionario viewbag con los datos de los roles del usuario
    public void CargarViewbag()
    {
        //Agrega los tipo de roles para visualizarlos en la vista
        ViewBag.RolUsuario = ModeloBD.PA_Rol_Select("").ToList();
    }
    //Controlador que levanta la vista trae al modelo para buscar el dato que se desea modificar
    public ActionResult ModificaRolUsuario(int Id_Usuario)
    {
        //Crea el modelo de la vista y llama al procedimiento almacenado
        PA_UsuarioID_Select_Result ModeloVista = ModeloBD.PA_UsuarioID_Select(Id_Usuario).FirstOrDefault();
        CargarViewbag();
        //Si posee algun valor(existe), lo envia a la vista
        if (ModeloVista != null)
        {
            return View(ModeloVista);
        }
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    //Envia los datos modificdos
    public ActionResult ModificaRolUsuario(PA_UsuarioID_Select_Result ModeloVista)
    {
        //Se crea una variable que llama el procedimiento almacenado para el cambio de rol
        int RegistrosAfectados = ModeloBD.PA_RolUsuario_Update(ModeloVista.Id_Usuario,ModeloVista.id_rol);
        //Se valida si se realizaron los cambios
        if (RegistrosAfectados > 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","El rol del usuario fue cambiado con éxito");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Hubo un error al momento de cambiar el rol del usuario");
        }
        //Es necesario agregar el método para se cargue en la vista
        CargarViewbag();
        //El resultado obtenido es pasado a la vista
        return View(ModeloVista);
    }
```

Este es el código de la vista:

```
@model Ferreteria_FYDBB.Models.PA_UsuarioID_Select_Result
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ModificaRolUsuario";
    string URLRegresar = Url.Action("ListaUsuario","Usuario");
}

<h2>ModificaRolUsuario</h2>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" id="frmCambioRol" class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="Id_Usuario" id="Id_Usuario" value="@Model.Id_Usuario"/>
        <br />
        <label name="Nombre" id="Nombre">@Model.Nombre  @Model.Apellido_1 @Model.Apellido_2</label>
        <br />
        <label>Rol</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="slctRol" name="slctRol">
                @{
                    foreach (Ferreteria_FYDBB.Models.PA_Rol_Select_Result Roll in ViewBag.RolUsuario)
                    {
                        if (Roll.Id_Rol == Model.id_rol)
                        {
                            <option value="@Roll.Id_Rol" selected>@Roll.Id_Rol-@Roll.Descripcion_Rol</option>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="@Roll.Id_Rol">@Roll.Id_Rol-@Roll.Descripcion_Rol</option>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @*<input type="submit" name="btnCambiar" id="btnCambiar" value="Cambiar Rol"/>*@
        <button type="submit">Cambiar</button>
        <a href="@URLRegresar">Regresar</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Estos son los resultados de la depuración:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, lo que es el ID del usuario esta con el numero 9, pero lo que es el rol esta en 0, cuando en realidad debería de contener en número 2 que es el ID del rol que se le asigno al usuario. El value/Valor  no se envía al controlador mientras que el ID del usuario si se envía. Ya he probado quitando las comillas del value/valor y colocandolo en la descripción del rol y obtengo mismo resultado.

Como puedo enviar el ID del rol al controlador en ese caso, ya que hace tiempo hice un proyecto con la misma forma y el ambos ID se enviaban al controlador.

Que puedo hacer en este caso?...

Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: En tu resultado de la depuración también te salta una excepción, ¿Qué pone ahí?

Comment: Es esto: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'

Comment: si te das cuenta estas recibiendo un objeto diferente al que solicitas en parametros, recibes FYDBB_WebEntities y solicitas PA_UsuarioID_Select_Result, eso puede ser la causa de tu excepción

Comment: A lo que tengo entendido, lo que es FYDBB_WebEntities es la instancia del modelo y el  PA_UsuarioID_Select_Result es el tipo complejo que me sirve como un "marco" de los datos que quiero solicitar.... Puede que este equivocado pero así lo entiendo....